# Multiple displays - how to configure in a correct way

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a setup with 3 screens:

- in the middle: laptop screen with resolution 2560x1440
- on the left
  and right: monitor screen with resolution 1920x1200

I managed to use GUI (System settings) in Ubuntu 18.04 to position external monitors correctly (with font scale 1.5) but I is not exactly what I would like.

The perfect setup would include 200% scaling for laptop screen and untouched scaling (100%) for external monitors.

I have tried to figure out how to use xrandr to do the work for me but I am lost. Could someone familiar with xrandr help me out?

Here is the output from xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
2560x1440     60.01*+  59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
1920x1440     60.00  
1856x1392     60.01  
1792x1344     60.01  
2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1400x900      59.96    59.88  
1280x960      60.00  
1440x810      60.00    59.97  
1368x768      59.88    59.85  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
1152x864      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
1024x768      60.04    60.00  
960x720       60.00  
928x696       60.05  
896x672       60.01  
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
960x600       59.93    60.00  
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
840x525       60.01    59.88  
864x486       59.92    59.57  
800x512       60.17  
700x525       59.98  
800x450       59.95    59.82  
640x512       60.02  
720x450       59.89  
700x450       59.96    59.88  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x405       59.51    58.99  
684x384       59.88    59.85  
680x384       59.80    59.96  
640x400       59.88    59.98  
576x432       60.06  
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
512x384       60.00  
512x288       60.00    59.92  
480x270       59.63    59.82  
400x300       60.32    56.34  
432x243       59.92    59.57  
320x240       60.05  
360x202       59.51    59.13  
320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 connected 1920x1200+0+54 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1200     59.95*+
1600x1200     60.00  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1152x864      75.00  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
800x600       75.00    60.32  
640x480       75.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
DP-2-2 connected 1920x1200+4480+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
1920x1200     59.95*+
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.88  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1152x864      75.00  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
800x600       75.00    60.32  
640x480       75.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```